# How to call onMessageReceived even when app is closed (FCM)?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know that there are few similar questions of this on stackoverflow. However, the answers are either not what I'm looking for or it's for GCM not FCM.

Right now, I'm able to call `onMessageReceived` both when the app is in foreground or background. But what I want is to call when the app is closed or swiped away from the task manager, not FORCE CLOSE. I'm able to receive push notifications even when app is closed but I want to call it `onMessageReceived` because I'm saving the push notifications on Firebase.

So the problem is I'm not able to save/write the data(push notifications) to Firebase when app is closed even though I receive it. I want to save the push notifications when app is closed. Am I able to call `onMessageReceived` when app is closed or any other methods I can do? I will post the codes below so it is easier to understand what I'm doing.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyAndroidFCMService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 createNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("msgBody", remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
        bundle.putString("time", currentDateTimeString);
        Intent new_intent = new Intent();
        new_intent.setAction("ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY");
        new_intent.putExtra("msg", bundle);

        sendBroadcast(new_intent);

        //create notification
//        createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }


    private void createNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this , MainActivity.class );
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel( true )
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_actionbar_tab);

 activityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("msg");
                String body = bundle.getString("msgBody");
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                String userID = user.getUid();
                Log.d("body", body);
                mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").push().setValue(body);


        if (activityReceiver != null) {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY");
            registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="25.3.0 " />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Login.ChooseLoginMethodActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

     <service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
```

Comment: Can you please show your manifest code

Comment: @Ancee I've included my manifest code.

Comment: Note that your `FCM` message must be not contains `notification` key (only use `data` key), if you want method `onMessageReceived` to be called when your app in background.

Comment: see my answer may be it helpful

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive
check this out there should be data in your payload to call onMessageReceived .means there should be key value pairs in your payload . tell your server team to send notification in key value form. I don't have much knowledge about server side . but what i know they send notification in key value pair

Comment: @Ancee Thanks, I have solved the problem. I moved the code where it will save the notification into database 'onReceive' to 'onMessageReceived' and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

on massage receive will not call when app is closed it will call only when APP IS on so you have to handle which class you have to redirect in mainfiest and put action in payout in server and get all data wen user click on notification using bundle.
use action in mainfiest like this give any name but same name in your server script or cade.

```
   <activity
            android:name="your activity name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="abc" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
```

in server make click action in you payload or json request like this

```
 notificatiin = array
(
'icon' => 'any',
'title' => 'any',
'body' => 'massage',
  'click_action' => 'abc'
  );
```

click antion same as mainfiest activity action when you click notification it will redect to activity wich is maithin in mainfiest whith action .

get notification  and save in redirected activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
 if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String someData= extras.getString("data");
String someData2 = extras.getString("data");
```